# Alphanumeric in a string

Tags: objective-c

I need help with fixing a code. 
I need it to look at the first two characters of the subclass. If it is alphanumeric (letters and number) the `subclassize=7`; if both the first two characters are numeric
`subclassize=4`.
This is the code:

```
int startrentex=0;
int rentexsize=0;
//int totalsize=0;
int subclasssize=7;
//int descriptionsize=9;
int currentlength=[enteredText length];
if(appdata.appSettings.BarCodeStyle==0) {
    if(currentlength>1){

        NSString *str = [enteredText substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
        int testint=[str intValue]; 
        if(![str isEqualToString:@"0"] && testint==0)
            subclasssize=7;
        else
            subclasssize=4;
        //a3fs12345hi there
        //1B3456712345hi there
    }
    startrentex=subclasssize;
    if(currentlength>subclasssize)
    {
        BOOL isspace=YES;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  This is Objective C code, isn't it?  The abundant use of `[…]` strongly suggests that is it not C++, at any rate.  You get better answers if you use the correct tags ([tag:objective-c] if my hypothesis is correct).

Comment: Unrelated note - please make use of the spacebar on your keyboard. "Is this easier to read?" or "Isthiseasiertoread?" Same goes for code. `if (currentLength > subclasssize)` is easier than `if(currentLength>subclasssize)`.

Comment: You need to tell us what's the problem with the current code, otherwise the question is incomplete.

Comment: The code at the moment looks over a sequence of numbers and letters. After it reads the characters it separates the numbers according. For example the number it looks at is [3DSONYTVB73032 1324VBR] . Right not it looks at it and if the second character and if it is a letter the size of the first set of numbers is 7 characters long. If the second character is a number, then the set of numbers are 4 characters long. I need it to look at the first two digits in this example "3D" and if it is a mix of numbers and letters I need the code to set the "Subclass' (what I call it) 7 characters long.

Comment: Even if its D3 or 3D it's a mixers of alphanumeric. If both of the fist two characters are both numbers then its 4 characters long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need it to look at the first two characters of the subclass.

If you want to look at *characters* then use the `NSString` method `- characterAtIndex:`. This will return you a value of type `unichar` - the type of unicode characters in Objective-C.

Once you have your first two characters you can test them.

> If it is alphanumeric (letters and number) the `subclassize=7`; if both the first two characters are numeric `subclassize=4`

To determine the class of a character you can use `NSCharacterSet`. This class provides standard sets of characters, e.g. `+ decimalDigitCharacterSet`, and a method to test for membership `- characterIsMember:`.

With these classes and methods you should be able to quickly solve your problem. You will find full details of these classes and methods in Apple’s documentation.

HTH